# How to restore expired WhatsApp chat history?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, restore, chat

My phone's internal memory is full so I'm planning to reset my entire phone in order to update my whatsapp, however I want to keep my old conversations.

How do I retrieve my WhatsApp conversations after it has expired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Helium backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup&hl=en) to backup all your chats, groups, etc. Moreover, this app can be used to backup all the applications on your phone.

You can store this backup on your PC, and when you reset your phone, you can upload the whole backup folder on your SD card and initiate a restore from Helium app.

If you are not rooted, you will need its desktop application to backup your phone. It's pretty simple and reliable. You can refer to [Helium Wiki](https://github.com/koush/support-wiki/wiki/Helium-Wiki) in case you get stuck.

Comment: Wow thank you. Thats brilliant. I will try that :)

Comment: Hi was wondering if you know how to increase my internal phone storage. The only apps I have in my phone are the compulsory ones that come with the phone, and WhatsApp & Tubemate. But I frequently get a message saying that its full.